# IDE for JBoss JSF development

Tags: eclipse, jsf, netbeans, jboss

I am planning to develop a medium to large size web application using JSF (plus PrimeFaces or other) for the view layer and EJB3 for business logic. The reason we've chosen EJB3 over more lightweight JSF beans that might only require a Servlet container (as opposed to an EJB3 container) is for additional EJB3 features like security. Since we are targeting deployment on JBoss AS I was wondering what IDE solution you would recommend. I've seen that both Eclipse and Netbeans support JBoss either out-of-the-box or with plugins.

Comment: Everyone have different choice. I HATE Eclipse and love Netbeans...

Comment: This isn't a question about one's favourite IDE hence I don't understand the down vote. There could be technical or pragmatical reasons why a certain IDE might have been better suited to the particular stack I am using. But I take it that the answer is that all are equally suited so it boils down to one's personal preferences.

Comment: @Parkar : Comment was not address to you. Sorry for not making this clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or even you can try [IntelliJ Idea](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/). All these IDEs has a support for all common servers (including JBoss) so that's really not a criterium for choosing IDE.

It just depends on what you are used to and if you have one of these IDEs already running (with Maven, Ant, SVN, Git or whatever you use for your project) then just go with it:-)